# Can ExtensionDataService be used from a PowerShell-based VSTS build task?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-devops-rest-api

I have created a PowerShell-based build task for Visual Studio Team Services (formerly Visual Studio Online). I have implemented the majority of the functionality I need, but for the last bit of functionality I need to be able to persist a small amount of data between builds.

The [ExtensionDataService](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/vss/sdk/services/extensiondata/extensiondataservice) seems like exactly what I want (in particular, the setValue and getValue methods), but [the documentation and examples I have found](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/data-storage) are for node.js-based build tasks:

```
    VSS.getService(VSS.ServiceIds.ExtensionData).then(function(dataService) {
    // Set a user-scoped preference
    dataService.setValue("pref1", 12345, {scopeType: "User"}).then(function(value) {
        console.log("User preference value is " + value);
    });
```

The previous page also has a partial example of calling the REST API, but I have gotten 404 errors when trying to use it to either save or retrieve values:

```
GET _apis/ExtensionManagement/InstalledExtensions/{publisherName}/{extensionName}/Data/Scopes/User/Me/Collections/%24settings/Documents
{
    "id": "myKey",
    "__etag": -1,
    "value": "myValue"
}
```

Can PowerShell be used to access the ExtensionDataService, either by using a library or by calling the REST API directly?

Comment: How do you send the REST request? Via tool or code? Could you set value by call dataService.setValue method in your extension? If so, you can capture the request URL via developer tool (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn255004(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I can't call `dataService.setValue` from my extension because I'm using PowerShell, and the developer tool won't be helpful right now because my extension is just a build task that doesn't have any browser-based components. I gave a request URL in a reply to one of your other comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call REST API through PowerShell.

Set value (**Put** request):

```
 https://[vsts name].extmgmt.visualstudio.com/_apis/ExtensionManagement/InstalledExtensions/{publisherName}/{extension id}/Data/Scopes/User/Me/Collections/%24settings/Documents?api-version=3.1-preview.1
```

Body (Content-Type:**application/json**)

```
{
  "id": "myKey",
  "__etag": -1,
  "value": "myValue"
}
```

Get value (**Get** request):

```
https://[vsts name].extmgmt.visualstudio.com/_apis/ExtensionManagement/InstalledExtensions/{publisherName}/{extension id}/Data/Scopes/User/Me/Collections/%24settings/Documents/mykey?api-version=3.1-preview.1
```

The publisher name and extension id could be get in package json file (e.g. vss-extension.json)

Regarding call REST API through PowerShell, you can refer to this article: [Calling VSTS APIs with PowerShell](http://blog.devmatter.com/calling-vsts-apis-with-powershell/)

Simple sample to call REST API:

```
Param(
   [string]$vstsAccount = "<VSTS-ACCOUNT-NAME>",
   [string]$projectName = "<PROJECT-NAME>",
   [string]$buildNumber = "<BUILD-NUMBER>",
   [string]$keepForever = "true",
   [string]$user = "",
   [string]$token = "<PERSONAL-ACCESS-TOKEN>"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$uri = "https://$($vstsAccount).visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/$($projectName)/_apis/build/builds?api-version=2.0&buildNumber=$($buildNumber)"

$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
```

PowerShell script to get the base URL:

```
Function GetURL{
param([string]$url)
$regex=New-Object System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("https:\/\/(.*).visualstudio.com")
$match=$regex.Match($url)
 if($match.Success)
    {
        $vstsAccount=$match.Groups[1]
        $resultURL="https://$vstsAccount.extmgmt.visualstudio.com"
    }
}
GetURL "https://codetiger.visualstudio.com/"
```

Comment: For {publisherName} I used the "publisher" value in vss-extension.json, and for {extension id} I used the "id" value in vss-extension.json. I get a `TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred.` error response for both PUT and GET requests to the URLs you gave.

Comment: @Chris What's the detail URL you used? How do you send the request? Could you upload and install your extension to VSTS?

Comment: I've been sending the requests using Postman, and an example URL for PUT is `https://codetiger.extmgmt.visualstudio.com/_apis/ExtensionManagement/InstalledExtensions/csdahlberg/CodeTigerVersionStamper/Data/Scopes/User/Me/Collections/%24settings/Documents?api-version=3.1-preview.1`. I can upload it to VSTS using the `tfx build tasks upload` command and use the code I currently have. I haven't figured out how to package a PowerShell extension into a VSIX file to upload to the marketplace, but I'll create a new question for that.

Comment: @Chris So you uploaded the extension to your VSTS, you can capture the requests for dataService.setValue function. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn255004(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I mentioned in one of my other comments that my extension only contains a PowerShell build task, so I cannot capture requests using my browser because I do not have anything that runs in the browser. I'd really rather not have to figure out how to add a node.js-based UI part to my extension just to reverse-engineer something that should be better documented.

Comment: @Chris You can do it in other type extension, such as web hub, dashboard widget. (I modified widget extension to call dataService.setValue function) (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/add-dashboard-widget) After getting the API URL, I made test in Postman.

Comment: After fixing another problem in my extension, I was finally able to get requests working by hard-coding `https://codetiger.extmgmt.visualstudio.com/` as the base URL, but that seems like something that should be obtainable using environment variables. The `SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONSERVERURI` variable returns `https://codetiger.visualstudio.com/`, but I can't find anything that gives me either the URL including `extmgmt` or just `codetiger` by itself. Do you know of any that do?

Comment: @Chris You can vsts account and combine the url again. I added the code to my answer, you can check it.

Comment: I don't particularly like this solution (it seems fragile, and could never work with on-premise TFS installations), but it looks like that's the best I can do right now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Chris did you manage to make this work? I also want to retrieve an extension document from another application, but I'm stuck with calling `https://$vstsAccount.extmgmt.visualstudio.com` with the personal access token. It always returns 401 (Unauthorized). Also the newer `https://extmgmt.dev.azure.com` url returns 401 on me.

Comment: Yep.

For the original PowerShell version of my task, I used `https://$vstsAccount.extmgmt.visualstudio.com`: https://github.com/csdahlberg/CodeTiger.AzureDevOps.Versioning/blob/8b52c87e7020ce0b599ab9331acee1d4d6987948/stamp-versions-task/v0/StampVersions.ps1#L317

For the newer node.js version, I used more built-in functionality: https://github.com/csdahlberg/CodeTiger.AzureDevOps.Versioning/blob/8b52c87e7020ce0b599ab9331acee1d4d6987948/stamp-versions-task/v1/index.ts#L49

In both cases, I enabled the `Allow scripts to access the OAuth token` option for the build phase.